# How To Upload Image From Admin Side on Django

Tags: python, django, web

In Models.py,

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Is Published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.choice_text
```

In settings.py, i added

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/media')
```

In mysite/urls.py,

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace= "polls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In index.html,

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
{% if latest_questions %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_questions %}
            <li><a href={% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}>
                <b>{{question.question_text}}</b>
                <img src="{{question.question_text.image.url}}">
            </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p> You have no questions. Please add some.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

but there seems to be no uploading of image which was what i wanted to add to poll app created from 'my first django app' videos on youtube.
Please help.

Comment: What does this have to do with Pycharm, which is an editor?

Answer (score 0):

Change this from:

```
<img src="{{question.question_text.image.url}}">
```

To the following one:

```
<img src="{{question.image.url}}">
```